# GAE - creating an app issue

Tags: google-app-engine

To get started with GAE, I started with url https://appengine.google.com/start. When I clicked Create Application button the browser got an infinite redirect loop on url https://accounts.google.com/b/0/Idv..... I tried different browsers on ubuntu and android. All get the same error. Please help what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try a different PC with a different network connection (i.e. not behind any proxy or similar). As it does work....

Comment: I've tried following: local wi-fi, connections over ssh tunneling to several vps' which located in different networks, mobile network connection - nothing seemed to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue with https proxy server. Thanks!